# thread with rvalue reference of an object

Tags: c++, c++14, rvalue-reference

I have a function which accepts an rvalue reference of on object and I want to run this function in a `std::thread`. Following piece of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class MyType {
public:
    explicit MyType(int m) : myint_(m) {}
    MyType(const MyType& ) = delete;
    MyType ( MyType&& ) = delete;
    MyType operator = (const MyType& ) = delete;
    MyType operator = (const MyType&&) = delete;

private:
   int myint_;
};

void Run(const MyType&& t) {
  // do somthing with t.     
}

int main()
{
    MyType m{100};
    std::thread t(Run, std::move(m));
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I have deleted the default move and copy constructor. In my case it might be possible to define a default move constructor but I would not like to have a copy constructor because `sizeof(MyType)` can be big and I am concerned about the memory when the copy constructors are called.

I need advice on how to achieve this.

Regards.

Comment: If `MyType` is non-copyable and non-movable, you can only pass it by reference: `std::thread t(Run, std::ref(m));`.

Comment: You can't. `std::thread` does not work this way. The only thing you can pass is ordinary lvalue references that get wrapped in `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry if this is to big of a question for the comments: Why does `std::thread` not work this way? A priori it seems certainly possible to just perfect-forward everything (and the constructor explicitly goes around this by using `std::decay`).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik is there any alternative way to transfer ownership of an object to another thread ?

Comment: ["The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value. If a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has to be wrapped (e.g. with `std::ref` or `std::cref`)."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)

Comment: You deleted move constructor and move assignment. How do you wan to transfer it then?

Comment: By definition, all parameters to a new execution thread function are moved/copied by value. That's how `std::thread` works. There's nothing you can do about it. Either pass it by reference, and make sure that the object does not go out of scope in its original execution thread until the new execution thread finishes using it, or instantiate it in dynamic scope, and use `std::unique_ptr`, or something similar.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I tried this with unique_ptr and to my surprise it now works. This leads me to ask how does this works in this scenerio as for unique_ptr also the copy constructors are deleted. (and for my case even though I allow move constructor it doesn't work) ..

Comment: unique_ptr's move constructor is sufficient. The unique_ptr is moved into the execution thread's parameter.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what I dont understand is that even if I enable move constructor in my class. It still gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @[SamVarshavchik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943312/sam-varshavchik) I have it working now with `std::unique_ptr`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class MyType {
public:
    explicit MyType(int m) : myint_(m) {}
    MyType(const MyType& ) = delete;
    MyType ( MyType&& ) = delete;
    MyType operator = (const MyType& ) = delete;
    MyType operator = (const MyType&&) = delete;

private:
   int myint_;
};

void Run(std::unique_ptr<MyType>&& t) {
  // do somthing with t.     
}

int main()
{
    auto m = std::make_unique<MyType>(100);
    std::thread t(Run, std::move(m));
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Follow up question: unique_ptr is not copyable and is only moveable. How does it works with it but not for my data type (even though I make it moveable) ??

Answer (score 0):

What is going on is that `std::thread` copies its arguments into something tuple-like, then in the thread invokes the function with those arguments.

In your specific case, the thread doesn't outlive the scope the `std::thread` object is created in.  This is not typical.

The easiest way to get what you want to work is:

```
MyType m{100};
std::thread t([&]{ Run(std::move(m)); });
t.join();
```

where you pass in a lambda and manage copying and lifetime yourself.

Note that if this thread outlives the scope where `m` is created, this is going to follow a dangling reference.

```
std::thread t([pm=std::make_unique<MyType>(100)]() mutable { Run(std::move(*pm)); });
```

is a version where I create the object directly on the heap, then use a smart pointer to carry it around with the thread.  A correctly written `std::thread` should only require its callable be movable (an incorrectly written one will store it in a std function can generate build errors here; you can swap unique ptr for shared ptr for modest additional overhead but get it to compile on a non-standard-compliant std thread).

---

My general rule of thumb is to *not* use the INVOKE-based threading helpers, but rather use no-argument lambdas and handle the argument storage and passing myself.

The threading APIs come from boost in a pre-lambda era of C++; lambdas are something you really should master anyhow, and can replace having to gain expertise in the quirks of INVOKE based APIs (even knowing what INVOKE is is something you don't need to know!)

(`std::invoke`, and `std::apply`, OTOH, are awesome, even though they are INVOKE; my main complaint is the violation of SRP (single responsibility principle), where we mix threading constructs with invocation constructs.)

Comment: If we add a move constructor to OP's class and declare `void Run(MyType)`, will `std::thread t(Run, std::move(m));` work correctly?

Comment: @Evg By the standard, yes.  Under some versions of MSVC which had bugs here, no.